# Does vegetable oil allow methane to pass through?

Tags: biochemistry, experimental-design, respiration

I'm doing an experiment investigating how temperature affects the rate of methanogenesis. I'm using a peat sample that will be kept in a conical flask connected to a gas syringe with a layer of Janus Green B administered (to indicate if aerobic conditions are present) and vegetable oil (to prevent air entry and to allow carbon dioxide to pass through). There are two main concerns I have about my experimental design at the moment. Firstly will methane also pass through the vegetable oil and secondly one of the pathways of methanogenesis (Carbon Dioxide + Hydrogen → Methane + Water) uses Carbon Dioxide as a reactant, so I'm worried that some of the carbon dioxide produced by the decomposition of acetic acid will be used in the other pathway and not arrive at the gas syringe. Does anybody have any suggestions about making my methanogenesis experiment feasible?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This question might be a better fit for chemistry.SE